# Query to get data type of SQL output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema

Say I run a query

```
select * from Table1 inner join Table 2 on .... etc
```

Is there a way to find the output schema (data type) of this query without having to look at the table schema of the individual tables used by the query?

Comment: Find out how?  Is querying the meta-tables sufficient?

Comment: Looking at your title coming into this, I was under the impression that you were looking for a `typeof` (C#) sort of operator in T-SQL. Now, though, I'm not sure I understand, since that query would return a `TABLE` (not particularly useful). So you want to print out the column list, given a query?

Comment: @TabAlleman particularly with the `JOIN` that the OP has in there, it could get a little daunting writing a query against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or what have you to grab the schema ahead of time. I think the goal is to be able to pass any arbitrary query and have it return the schema resulting from said query, with no prior knowledge of the query's contents or referenced tables.

Comment: Its for MS SQL Server.
Is there a way to wrap my select query in some other query to get the column schema of the select query's output?

Comment: 2012 has [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff878602.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith, that's an awesome feature I didn't know about, but the tag on the OP's post says 2008R2 ...

Comment: @AHiggins yes. Hence comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the column names are unique, you could do:

```
SELECT *
INTO #tmp
FROM Table1 inner join Table 2 on ...

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help N'#tmp';
```